# SQL query - add summary row

Tags: sql, grafana

I'm trying to add summary row for my gradana sqlite query.

My current query is like this:

```
SELECT
date(close_date) AS "Date",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Wins,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Losses,
(SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Avg",
(SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 WHERE date(close_date) IS NOT NULL GROUP BY date(close_date) ORDER BY Date DESC
```

And it outputs table like this:

```
Date         Wins      Losses      Avg     Profit
2021-09-23      1           0        3       68.8
2021-09-22      2           0      1.7       78.7
2021-09-21      5           0      4.8        538
2021-09-20     14           0      1.7        445
```

How can I add summary row to this table ?
Something like this:

```
Date         Wins      Losses      Avg     Profit
Total          22           0      2.8     1130.5   
2021-09-23      1           0        3       68.8
2021-09-22      2           0      1.7       78.7
2021-09-21      5           0      4.8        538
2021-09-20     14           0      1.7        445
```

Summary row should be the first row.
Wins is sum of all wins.
Losses is sum of all losses.
Avg is average of all Avgs.
Profit is sum of all profits.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
  [close_date] = COALESCE(close_date, 'Total') AS date,
  [close_profit_abs] = SUM(close_profit_abs),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit > 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Wins,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trades WHERE close_profit < 0 AND date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS Losses,
(SELECT AVG(close_profit * 100) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Avg",
(SELECT SUM(close_profit_abs) FROM trades WHERE date(c2.close_date) = date(close_date)) AS "Profit"
FROM trades c2 WHERE date(close_date) IS NOT NULL GROUP BY date(close_date) ORDER BY Date DESC
```

but it all gets f**ked up.. My sql skills is not enough for this..
Can anyone help me with this ? I can find guides much more simplier what I have here and when I try to implement them to my existing code then it all get messy.

Any help is appreciated.. Thx

Comment: Some databases have - rollup/cube/grouping. That would be the best bet.
Or else, as a quick work around - 
```<your query> union all select sum(wins), sum(losses), avg(avg), sum(profit) from <your_query>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this ('summary row' UNION ALL 'your query'):

I improve your query (I take out your subqueries), let me know if the result is not correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM (

    SELECT 
           'Total' AS "Date",
           count(CASE WHEN close_profit > 0 THEN 1 END) AS Wins,
           count(CASE WHEN close_profit < 0 THEN 1 END) AS Losses,
           AVG(close_profit * 100) AS "Avg",
           SUM(close_profit_abs)  AS "Profit"
    FROM trades
    WHERE close_date IS NOT NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
           date(close_date) AS "Date",
           count(CASE WHEN close_profit > 0 THEN 1 END) AS Wins,
           count(CASE WHEN close_profit < 0 THEN 1 END) AS Losses,
           AVG(close_profit * 100) AS "Avg",
           SUM(close_profit_abs)  AS "Profit"
    FROM trades
    WHERE close_date IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY date(close_date)) AS sq

ORDER BY "Date" DESC;
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you.
 "ORDER BY Date DESC) AS sq" <-- DESC seems not to work on here. Total summary is first row but then the order of the dates starts from the oldest - I would rather have newest date right after the summary row..  And small little details (no necessary) - I would like to see "Total" on the first row on the "Date" column where is empty field now... other wise this is super awesome!

Comment: You are welcome @user3647376! I updated my query. I take out the first `ORDER BY`, the important here is the last one. I add "Total" to `Date` column on row summary.